# T-SQL Select values from the end of a string which are between 2 characters

Tags: t-sql

I have tried looking in to `Reverse` and `CharIndex` but I just can't seem to get it to work.

I have a table with a column full of strings, all of which end with `aVALUESa`

The `VALUES` are a number and vary in length, how do I select these values?

Comment: You could use regex. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Comment: Your sample string suggests that `VALUES` is not at the end because there is an `a` at the end. Is `a` always `a`? If so, why do you store it at all?

Comment: a is always a, it is always aVALUESa at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your strings always end with the pattern 'aVALUESa' where the 'a' at the start and end is the literal 'a', you can try this:

```
select reverse(substring(reverse(colname),2,charindex('a',reverse(colname),2)-2))
from yourtable
```